# wpf, c#, renderTargetBitmap of viewport3D without assigning it to a window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I create a Viewport3D in code:

```
Viewport3D CurViewport3D = new Viewport3D();
CurViewport3D = CreateViewportWithContent(); //fill the viewport with some content
BitmapSource bmp;
var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(600, 300, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

renderTargetBitmap.Render(CurViewport3D);
bmp = (BitmapSource)renderTargetBitmap;
PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
using (Stream stm = File.Create("outp.png")){ png.Save(stm);}
```

But unfortunately the outp.png is empty without any content.
In case I'm applying the viewport to a window:

```
MainGrid.Children.Add(CurViewport3D); //MainGrid is part of the window
```

Everything works perfect. The outp.png is not empty.
Does anyone have any idea what to do to get the correct image without applying the viewport to a window?

Problem solved! I can not answer my question - don't know why ...
I added the following sequence:

```
int width = 500;
int height = 300;
CurViewport3D.Width = width;
CurViewport3D.Height = height;
CurViewport3D.Measure(new Size(width, height));
CurViewport3D.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! I can not answer my question - don't know why ... I added the following sequence:

```
int width = 500;
int height = 300;
CurViewport3D.Width = width;
CurViewport3D.Height = height;
CurViewport3D.Measure(new Size(width, height));
CurViewport3D.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
```